# Manipulating other elements on condition true, Reactjs jsx

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a mapping loop on select options. On condition true, one option gets selected. Now i want one element out of select tag to have a class "check" if condition is true.

```
<div className="select-style">
    <select>
        {xarray.map((heading, index) => 
            {return heading.headingis.toLowerCase().indexOf('earning') != -1 ?
                <option value="{heading.headingis}" key={index} selected>{heading.headingis}</option>
                :
                <option value="{heading.headingis}" key={index}>{heading.headingis}</option>
            }
       )}                                                 
    </select>
  </div>
<div className="mapping-check"></div>
```

[image]

1. If condition `1` is true, `2` should have class "mapping-check". Else no class.

**EDIT:** There are multiple dropdowns and each will have a **check div**.

[image]

How would I achieve this?

Comment: What you mean by: "each will have a check div"?

Comment: Mean, there are multiple rows (dynamic), do i have to maintain state for each `<div className="mapping-check"></div>` ?

Comment: Each dropdown will have a different `<div>` to manipulate, or it will be only one `<div>` with multiple classes?

Comment: please check paste: https://pastebin.com/8ipy6zwu

Each will have different div to add check.

Comment: Then you can create a component which will have the `<select>` and the `.mapping-check` div, and it will handle the `state` change internally.

Comment: Great, i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have an `onChange` event for the `<select>` tag, and depending on the selected option, you can change a `state property` like `checked` to be `true`.

Then you'll have a ternary condition like:

`<div className={this.state.checked ? : 'mapping-check' : ''}></div>`

Instead of the empty string, you can have another class, or multiple classes.

Comment: Thanks, Please check EDITED question.